# MVC Custom Validation overwritten by Standard Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with custom validation. I have a ViewModel:

```
public class CityViewModel
{
    [ForeignKey(ErrorMessageResourceName = "County")]
    public int CountyId { get; set; }

    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

I created a custom validation class named `ForeignKey` that contains this code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ForeignKeyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyInfo propretyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName);
        ResourceManager manager = Resource.ResourceManager;

        if (propretyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType && propretyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
            if (value != null && (int)value == 0) {
                return new ValidationResult(manager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));
            }
            else {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
        else if (value == null || (int)value == 0) {
            return new ValidationResult(manager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This method works perfectly and return the error correctly. The problem is in the action in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DataSourceRequest request, CityViewModel model)
{
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // Some code

            return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Some code
    }

    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

If `CountyId` is null (really is 0 but during validation before entering in the method `Create` can be null) my `ModelState` contains, for `CountyId` field, this error "The CountyId field is required." instead of my error passed to `ForeignKey` custom attribute.

If I use this code:

```
TryValidateModel(model);
```

Then `ModelState` contains both errors, so before calling `TryValidateModel` I should use:

```
ModelState["CountyId"].Errors.Clear();
```

How can I say to MVC not to overwrite my error during first validation? I prefer to use simply `ModelState.IsValid`. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You property is `int` which means it must have a value so the Required validation is performed first. If you want to return your error message, make the property `int?` (nullable)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the answer. I know that I can set property nullable but I need it be non nullable. Can I suppress `Required` validation?

Comment: You could try Excluding the Id in the Create method parameters ie:
Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")], CityViewModel model)

Comment: AFAIK, you cant. Required validation will always be called before anther validation (and therefore its message added first)

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon Thanks! Your solution works fine but I would prefer avoid adding attributes. I will keep it as an alternative.

Comment: If it works I'll stick it as an answer then, I couldn't quite remember if custom validation would be able to use the property after it was excluded.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you know a way to get ModelState in `IsValid` method?

Comment: Bit unclear why you have accepted the answer you did. By excluding `ID` from binding, it means that the value of the property is initialized to its default (`0`) so the `Required` error message is not displayed, but if the user has entered/selected a value for `ID`, then it will be ignored, making including your property and using your `ForeignKey` pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Excluding the Id in the Create method parameters

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResultCreate([Bind(Exclude = "Id")], CityViewModel model)
```

Comment: How can this possibly solve OP's problem. By excluding the property from binding, its value will be initialized to zero, which triggers a validation error and `ModelState` is invalid so the view will be returned to correct it. The view will show the previous value the user has entered/selected (confusing the poor user who gets an error message telling him that its invalid even though its not) so the users posts a valid value again, its ignored and reset to zero, and the endless cycle repeats. Nothing ever gets saved and the user will no doubt never use the app again.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tested this solution and it works. When I tried to validate my model, validation bypass `Required` validation but not my `ForeignKey` validation.

Comment: Yes it does - but what is the point. If the user entered something valid (say) 5, when you go to save the data it will try to save the value as `0` (because the value is `0` - not `5` because its not bound). That of course would throw an exception. And if your checking `ModelState` and returning the view if invalid - you just end up with an endless loop (and a whole lot of angry users coming after you)

Comment: Surely the ID can only be null/0 because it's on the create method. There would certainly be problems if you did this on an update.

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon, Its not an ID - the property is `CountyId` for a model associated with class named `City` and its marked with an attribute named `ForeignKey` :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke When I tried to save my `City` object the `CountyId` contained the correct value.

Comment: @erikscandola, If you included `[Bind(Exclude = "CountyId")]`, then that would be impossible :) - the value of `CountryId` would always be `0`